# iOS 7 Camera.app horizontal 3d transform

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-animation, ios7

I'm really interested in this effect introduced in iOS 7 Camera app:

http://i41.tinypic.com/2a0hwk8.jpg

Notice, how "Pano" option is transformed - as if it is goes on a circular path to the right and dissappears. What kind of transformation can achieve this effect? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: the link is dead for me

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a transform that is applied and adjusted when the view in question (the label) reaches a certain position (which would normally be done with KVO or similar).

However, a good place to start would be the iOS 7 picker view, which has a similar 3D effect, but in the vertical rather than the horizontal. They are probably achieved the same way, and the advantage with the picker is you can inspect its view hierarchy in your own apps.